# ¿Como vuelvo a redireccionar la salida estándar por pantalla después de usar una pipe?

Tags: c, redirección

Me ocurre lo siguiente. Estoy escribiendo en una pipe con fprintf, y para que eso pueda pasar necesito hacer una redirección de stdout. El problema es que después de eso tengo que seguir sacando mensajes por pantalla en el programa sin usar la salida estándar de error.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n_real_cintas; i++){

        close(1);
        dup(tuberia[1]);

        fprintf(stdout, "%i", datos_entrada[i].id_cinta);
        wait(&pid[i]);
```

/*Aquí necesito volver a colocar la salida estándar de salida correctamente para imprimir que todo ha salido bien en el hijo.*/

```
    ----------redireccion----------
    printf("Todo OK");
```

¿Como vuelvo a colocar correctamente en la salida estándar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que *clonarla* **antes** de hacer el `fork( )`:

```
FILE *original_stdout = fdopen( dup( 1 ), "a+" ); // Clonamos y obtenemos FILE*
```

Cuando la necesites, solo haces

```
fprintf( original_stdout, "Todo OK");
```

Comment: ¡¡Muchísimas gracias!! ¡¡Eres un máquina!!

Comment: De nada; un placer :-)